# Printing a thermal ticket using PrintDocument with a Bluetooth-connected printer using .NET in Windows10

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I would like to know how to print a thermal ticket using PrintDocument with a Bluetooth-connected printer using .NET in a Windows 10.

If I connect the printer via USB, there is no problem. Here is a simple code version I am currently using:

```
public void PrintTicketUSB(string printerName)
{            
    var printDocument = new PrintDocument();            
    printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
    printDocument.PrintPage += (sender, e) => PrintTicketPage(e.Graphics);
                 
    printDocument.Print();
}

private void PrintTicketPage(Graphics graphics)
{        
    float yPos = 0;
    int padding = 5;
    Font fontTitol = new Font("Arial", 40, FontStyle.Bold);
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);            
    
    float yPos = padding;

    graphics.DrawString("Title", fontTitol, Brushes.Black, padding, yPos);
    yPos += fontTitol.GetHeight();
    
    graphics.DrawString("Hello world", font, Brushes.Black, padding, yPos);
    yPos += font.GetHeight();
}
```

When I connect the printer via Bluetooth (Windows 10), I assign it to COM3 and use this code, which works:

```
public void PrintTicketBT()
{           
    var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
        
    if(!serialPort.IsOpen)
        serialPort.Open();

    serialPort.Write("Hello world\n");
    serialPort.Close();
}
```

Is there a way to use PrintDocument with Bluetooth? Are there any references I can consult?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try to add some references that you already looked up online so people do not lose time in reading a page that won't help you.

Comment: After some persistence, I have successfully installed the Bluetooth printer as a local printer. Once I allocated the COM3 port to the Bluetooth device, I proceeded to reinstall the printer drivers. Then, through the advanced properties settings, I switch the port from USB to COM3. So, with the right knowledge, this process proved to be straightforward! :P

Comment: Great @Marc, can you then close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I managed to solve my problem and configure the Bluetooth printer as a local printer. These are the steps:

*Please note that my Windows 10 is in Spanish, so the names may be different on your system. Sorry, I still don't have enough reputation to include inline pictures :(

1. Pair the printer in the Bluetooth section.
2. Click on "More Bluetooth options".

[screenshot_of_configuration_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDXVn.png)

1. Open the "COM Ports" tab.
2. Press the "Add" button.
3. Select the printer from the list or click "Explore".
4. Click "OK".

[screenshot_of_configuration_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrCZ3.png)

Remember the COM port assigned. In my case, it is "COM3".

[screenshot_of_configuration_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbwxH.png)

Now, go to the printers and select your printer (previously installed).

1. Click on "Manage Printer" or a similar option.

[screenshot_of_configuration_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luG4r.png)

Finally, assign the COM port to your printer:

1. Open the printer properties.
2. Open the "Ports" tab.
3. Select the COM port that we saw before in the Bluetooth settings.
4. Click "OK".

[screenshot_of_configuration_5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue9og.png)

This configuration worked for me! I hope it helps somebody else!

Comment: Hi @Marc, I recently purchased bluetooth thermal printer and was looking for a solution to use it from c# and came across your solution. Thank you for providing the solution that you have discovered.